# NSIS convert int to hex string

Tags: installation, nsis

I have an NSIS script that run external program, this program returns C++ type HRESULT (unsigned int32) and NSIS operates with this value as signed int32. And I need to spent time to convert value correctly.

Is there simple way to do this automatically in NSIS script?

Update: Solution is to convert value with NSIS command like this
IntFmt $0 "0x%X" $0

Comment: What's about to hard code the return values recalculated? E.g. if your programm returns -1 to expect 0xffffffff. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NSIS variables are strings but they are converted to numbers internally when required.

You can use [`IntCmpU`](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#intcmpu) ($0 U>= $1 etc in LogicLib syntax) to compare unsigned numbers and `IntFmt` to format a number any way you like...

..and HRESULT should be treated as signed; <0 for errors, 0=S_OK and >0 for S_FALSE and counts.